# How can I get a clean response from POST request and save it in a json file

Tags: node.js, json

I have the following code for POST request with nodejs and hapi framework:

```
server.route({
        method: "POST",
        path: "/newdata",
        config: {
            validate: {
                query: Joi.object({
                    alert: Joi.boolean().default(true)
                })
            }
        },
        handler: (request, h) => {
            fs.readFile('./data.json', (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Error reading file: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    const object = JSON.parse(data);

                    object.push(JSON.stringify(request.payload));
                    console.log(object)
                    fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify(object, null, 4), (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            return request.payload;
        }
    });
```

The response which a get looks like this : "{\"name\":\"Johny Crumpy\",\"corp\":\"USA\"}". How can I save it in the json file without "" everywhere and . In the json file it should like like this: {
"name": "Steve Ballmer",
"corp": "Microsoft"
},

Comment: you're stringifying twice...so you end up with (parts of the) data being double-encoded. Try changing `object.push(JSON.stringify(request.payload));` to `object.push(request.payload);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting these extra quotes because you are doing `JSON.strigify` twice. Try this.

```
        handler: (request, h) => {
         fs.readFile('./data.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`Error reading file: ${err}`);
            } else {
                const object = JSON.parse(data);

                object.push(request.payload);
                console.log(object)
                fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify(object, null, 4), (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                    }
                });
            }
         });

         return request.payload;
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that write `[object Object]` to the file? You're right that there should be only one `JSON.stringify`, but that should be at the one at `object.push` line...